# Can I play a straight with phoenix on top of a 1-A straight?

Tags: tichu

Is it authorized to play a *2, ..., Ace, Phoenix* straight on top of a *1,..., Ace* straight ?

Comment: Was this actually a situation you encountered??

Comment: As a matter of fact, yes :-D at the daily lunch session at work

Comment: Wow! In a very large number of games, I've seen someone have a 1-Ace straight twice ever (same person both times), but both times it used the Phoenix.

Comment: Heh. We're not your _average_ tichu player I guess ;) j/k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

When using the Phoenix as a wild card, it must always take the value of another regular card from 2-A. Because there is no card with value "Ace + 1", there's no card there for the Phoenix to stand in for.

Only a bomb can go over any Ace high straight.